# how document changes on a project?

Tags: documentation

i am working on some modules,actually change them.
but i don't know how i should document changes in a way that be clear and usefull for future changes.
would someone help me on this issue?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your project is written in one of the languages [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) supports, I strongly recommend using that to document your code.

By using Doxygen comments in your source code, you can easily generate documentation in a number of formats by running one command.

Comment: thanks.i use php.i will try your suggestion.

Comment: Great! PHP is one of the languages supported by Doxygen.